# Why do i get an "array" text in sql table, after uploading a file and it's name?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I send a form, which loads up a picture to a  server, and send the name of the picture into a database. Instead of the name, i got an "array" text. Do I make a base mistake, or the problem will be deeper?

Here's some lines of my code, if it helps.

```
<form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />
    <input name = "button" type = "button" id = "button" 
    value = "Küldés" onclick="subm(this.form,'_blank');">
</form>

$target_path = "images/clients/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']); 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']). 
    "Image has been uploaded";
}

$user_image= ($_POST['user_image'].['name']); 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function subm(f,newtarget) {
    f.submit();
    alert('Kép sikeresen feltölve!');
}

uploadpic.php sql

mysqli_query( $sqlconnection,  "UPDATE markers SET user_image = '$user_image' WHERE user_name ='".$_SESSION['user_name']."'");

index.php sql

$sql = "INSERT INTO markers " . "( user_image)".
"VALUES('$user_image')";
```

Comment: Missing the Ajax part.

Comment: What is your databse sql query?

Comment: Pass $_FILES['user_image']['name'] variable in sql query for image name

Comment: Neither worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like error in this line:

`$user_image= ($_POST['user_image'].['name']);`

Try this:

`$user_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];`

Comment: Can you check the values before query execution? `print_r($user_image); print_r($_FILES); die;`

Comment: It's very interesting. With this line of code, after post the values, i got an "Array()" text, on my page. Can you explain me what does it mean?